# Modelling a full 360º rotation with a swing using a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, models

Kay so basically I modelled the *Kiiking* sport ( which consits on swinging on a stiff-rodded swing till you can reach the top and do the full swing ) using a change to polars 
$ (r,\theta) $ 
 in the y-x plane so that $e_{r}$ and $e_{\theta}$ are the polar unit basis vectors defined in cartesians as

$e_{r} = cos(\theta)e_{x} + sin(\theta)e_{y}$

$e_{\theta} = -sin(\theta)e_{x} + cos(\theta)e_{y}$

I suppose that the Kiiker is the mass on a simple pendulum. For allowing this Kiiker to crouch and stand on the swing, I translated that situation into the center of mass (this is, the place where the mass is, in the pendulum) moving up and down the rod, which means that

$r = r(t)e_{r}$ ,

$ \text{r(t) being the distance from the pivot to the center of mass of the swing at the instant t}$

Modelling this way the pendulum, and solving the components of the 2nd Newton law, I got these equations for $\theta(t)$ and $r(t)$:

$r\ddot\theta + 2\dot r\dot\theta = -gsin(\theta)$

$\ddot r - r\dot\theta^2 = gcos(\theta) - \frac{T}{m}$

where T is the tension and m the mass.

**From now on** I have many ideas to continue that I don't know how to execute. The Kiiker must be crouched when reaching the bottom and stand up when reaching the end of the swing (this is, when the velocity is zero), so I thought about saying that

$r(t)=r_{max} \ \forall t : \theta (t)=0 $ (this is, crouched on the bottom)

$r(t)=r_{min} \ \forall t : \dot\theta (t)=0 $ (this is, stands up when the swing is turning back)

But I don't know if this is the good approach, or if this works for something. I know I want this to be satisfied in the model but... it's actually possible to define $r(t)$ in terms of $\theta(t)$?

Because $\theta(t)$ also depends on $r(t)$ right?

I'm confused
[image: picture of the model][image]

Comment: Your second differential equation is wrong. It should be dot theta square

Comment: @Eli that's true, already changed it

Comment: I'm confused can you please draw a picture of your Modell?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to know that to complete a full circle, $v\ge \sqrt {5gl}$ must be satisfied.

Comment: For your reference when math formatting sine or cosine use `\sin` or `\cos` to use upright characters for functions. Do you spot the difference $$\begin{matrix} g\,\sin(\theta) & \text{vs.} & g\,sin(\theta) \end{matrix}$$